# Resizing images using PHP without using headers

Tags: php, html, css, image, magento

I have a newsfeed connected to my Magento site. I display feeds as a list on my sidebar with images. Now, I want the images for the feeds to be thumbnail size when you right click and open it. Right now, it's 600x400 but I want it to be around 95x60.

I am aware of how to resize magento images but the images come from a different, non-magento site. So what I did for this after some research is this:

```
foreach($channel as $item) {
    preg_match('/<*img[^>]*src *=["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $item->content, $matches);
    foreach($i = 0; $i <= count($item->category); $i++) {
        if($i < 2) {
            $file = $matches[1];
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor(60,95);
            imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 95, $width, $height);
            $image = $new_image;
            echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode(imagejpeg($image))."' />";
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to immediately display the image after it is resized, hence the data:image/jpeg;base64 part but strangely this isn't working for me. Why is this? How can I resize the image without using a header and without saving the image. I've been stuck with this problem for more than a day now. Please advise.

I know I can use with and height in html but that's different from what I'm trying to achieve. I need it to permanently resize with so that if you try to download the image from the list, it will still be thumbnail size(95x60) not the normal size(600x400). Basically (hope this is clear), I need to make the actual size of the thumbnail 95x60 if someone tries to download or open the image.

Comment: Give a specified height / width in the HTML?

Comment: yes, yes. I am aware of that. But I need it to resize as a thumbnail permanently. Like if you try to save the image from the list, you will get the image size displayed, not one four times bigger than it.

Comment: You said *How can I resize the image without using a header and **without saving the image***. Now you are saying you want to save the image. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to relay what I mean clearly. Hopefully this will be better. I mean like you see the image on the list right as a thumbnail right? If for example, I'm a visitor and I wanted to try and save that thumbnail, I'd get the 600x400 normal size image instead of the thumbnail(65x90). Basically, I need the thumbnail image's actual size to be 65x90 if anyone tries to open the image or download it.

Comment: Could you post a base64 encoded image? Or test it yourself at http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/ ?

Comment: In that case, you must at some point download the image and re-serve it from your server. Whether you do so by putting it into base-64 encode for the content or serving it as a file is irrelevant.

Comment: @virmaior, yeah, I've tried downloading the image to the server. But it's not downloaded at all. My folder permission's already 777

Comment: @ArendE, yeah. I've checked my image. Strangely it returned string similar to the decoded image not the encoded one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$image = $new_image;
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode(imagejpeg($image))."' />";
```

To this:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($new_image);
$image = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean();
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($image)."' />";
```

And you should be done :)

Comment: It worked. But it's doing something strange. When I try this on my localhost, the image is displayed correctly but when I transferred the same code to the server, it just showed a black-filled square instead of the actual image.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I've accidentally omitted an important part of my code so I got errors. Thanks a lot for your help.